# Map Annotation SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

i have problem with showing sheets. When tap on Map Annotation it shows same view on every annotation. Need to have different views on every map annotation

**MapView**

```
struct MapView1: View {
@State private var showModal = false
@State var menuOpened = false
@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.2466700, longitude: 76.9226100), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.08))

var places = [
    Place2(name: "Empire State Building1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.222038, longitude: 76.934758), view: AnnotationView21(), image: .Dot),
    Place2(name: "Empire State Building2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.226620, longitude: 76.918578), view: AnnotationView22(), image: .circle),
    Place2(name: "wwww", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.222513, longitude: 76.954801), view: AnnotationView23(), image: .rog)
]

var views: [any View] = [AnnotationView23(), AnnotationView21()]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: places) { place in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: place.coordinate) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showModal = true
                    }, label: {
                        PlaceAnnotationView3(place: place)
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
                                LocationDetailsView3(place: place.view)
                                        .presentationDetents([.large, .medium, .fraction(0.45)])
                            }
                    });
                    NavigationLink(destination: LocationDetailsView2(place: place), label: {
                        PlaceAnnotationView2()
                    })
                }
            }
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avaeb.png]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please don't take screenshots of your code and errors. Instead you should include them in your question as text. That way it is easier for people to work with it. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

your places array are literally the same place, add different locations

```
var places = [
Place2(name: "Empire State Building", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.222038, longitude: 76.934758), view: AnnotationView22()),
Place2(name: "Empire State Building", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.226620, longitude: 76.918578), view: AnnotationView22())
]
```

this my code to show an annotation in a modal

```
NavigationLink(destination: mapLocation(region: region, listing: listing)) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                                Text(listing.address ?? "")
                            }
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
                            .frame(alignment: .leading)
                        }.frame(alignment: .leading)
```

```
struct mapLocation: View {
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    
    var listing: Listings
    
    var body: some View {

        
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region,annotationItems: [listing]) { listing1 in
            // ... create a custom MapAnnotation
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: listing1.latitude, longitude: listing1.longitude)) {
                
                PlaceAnnotationView(title: listing.priceShort ?? "")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: updated code here